# On the definition of finitely generated algebras

Tags: commutative-algebra, finitely-generated

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity, I have seen that
$A$ is a finitely generated $R$-algebra if and only if it is isomorphic to a quotient ring of the form $R[X_1,\dots,X_n]/I$ by an ideal $I\subset R[X_1,\dots,X_n]$.

Here when they say isomorphic, are we talking about homomorphisms of rings? or does it have to be an $R$ algebra homomorphism? Thank you.

Comment: It's an $R$-algebra homomorphism(for instance, see Chapter $2$ of Atiyah-Macdonald).  I don't have a counterexample for the ring homomorphism though.